# is cplusplus.com wrong? Pointers and string literals

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

In [this page "Pointers and string literals" section](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) the web site says `const char * foo = "hello";` and when we do output foo it shall return the address of the string literals, I tried this at home, but I get `"hello"`, and when I do `*foo` I also get `"hello"`, my question is is the website wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqJjI.png)

Comment: How are you doing the output?   Several output methods are required to do EXACTLY as you describe when outputting a pointer to `char` (i.e. they output what is at the address, rather than the address itself).

Comment: I did cout<<foo and it gave me "hello", is the operator << overloaded

Comment: @szd116 `cout << static_cast<void*>(foo);` will output the value of the pointer, i.e. the address it points to. `operator<<` is overloaded for `char*` and take it as a c-style string.

Comment: Ok, thank you, so i guess cplusplus.com isn't 100% correct

Comment: @szd116: I don't see where that page says what you say it says. That section doesn't say anything about output.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley just edited the original post, please see the highlighted portion in the screenshot.

Comment: @szd116: The highlighted text is correct. Note that it says nothing about output. It is saying that the value stored in the pointer is an address, not a letter or a string. That it gets printed as a string is the behavior of the function which interprets it.

Comment: That site is not very good; I suggest not using its tutorials

Comment: What's with all the questions about pointers to string literal today?  And why are they any more confusing that pointers to just plain-old-strings?

Comment: That should be `static_cast<void const*>(foo)`, @songyuanyao.

Answer (score 1):

The following code explains everything.

```
const char *foo = "hello";  
cout << static_cast<const void *>(foo) << endl;  //result is address of "hello" 
cout << foo << endl;  //result is "hello"
cout << *foo << endl; // result is 'h'
```

`cout << static_cast<const void *>(foo)` invokes the following function.

```
_Myt& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL operator<<(const void *_Val)
```

`cout << foo` invokes the following function.

```
template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& operator<<(
        basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr,
        const char *_Val)
```

`cout << *foo` invokes the following function.

```
   template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& operator<<(
        basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr, char _Ch)
```

Pay attention to the last parameter of the above called functions.
The following snapshot comes from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/. The content is correct, nothing wrong.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, now I understand